# Android Recyclerview GridLayoutManager when row given layout doesn't wrap its content

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a color picker application by using Recyclerview and GridlayoutManager for listing the colors. I am using ImageButton for presenting the colors. There are two recyclerviews, first one displays main colors that i made up and the second one displays the tint and shadow of the selected color from the first one. My code is ugly but this is for experimenting so right now i just want to make the second recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager be in two rows and 4 columns. I could make it with the code below but it only shows the first 4 colors and for the other ones i have to scroll down the view.
[image]

[image]

MainActivity:

```
package tr.com.beyes.colorpicker;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.content.res.TypedArrayUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources r=getResources();
        int[] fontColors = r.getIntArray(R.array.fontcolors);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fontColorView);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,11, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


        RecyclerView recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fontColorViewSub);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(this,4);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager2);

        int[] tint = new int[8];
        tint[0]=(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
        int red = Color.red(fontColors[0]);
        int green = Color.green(fontColors[0]);
        int blue = Color.blue(fontColors[0]);
        for(int i=1; i<7;i++){
            red = (int) (red + (255-red) * 0.25);
            green = (int) (green + (255-green) * 0.25);
            blue = (int) (blue + (255-blue) * 0.25);
            tint[i]=(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
        }
        tint[7]=(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        ColorPickerAdapter colorPickerAdapter2 = new ColorPickerAdapter(tint,this, null);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(colorPickerAdapter2);

        ColorPickerAdapter colorPickerAdapter = new ColorPickerAdapter(fontColors,this,colorPickerAdapter2);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(colorPickerAdapter);


    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="tr.com.beyes.colorpicker.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fontColorView"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fontColorViewSub"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

colorbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fontColorBox"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `setHasFixedSize(true)` to `recyclerView`  and `recyclerView2`

**2.** Update `gridLayoutManager2` parameter as below:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager2 = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
```

**3.** Use `NestedScrollView` as a container of your `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="tr.com.beyes.colorpicker.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fontColorView" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fontColorViewSub"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: Didn't work.. It looks the same but the only difference this time is the view started scrolled down to the second row. I want to display 2 rows at the same time without scrolling

Comment: setHasFixedSize(true) to recyclerviews. check my updated answer

Comment: I did that too.. same :(

Comment: Try adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to LinearLayout

Comment: Still the same. I wonder if i need to change the height of the recyclerview dynamically ?

Comment: can you please try with android:layout_height="match_parent" to 2nd recyclerview

Comment: you mean match_parent i assume.. Didnt work either :(

Comment: Last try android:fillViewport="true" to NestedScrollView

Comment: Neither of them didnt work. The problem is i change the background color of each cells. And I need them to be aligned according to the screen i mean they need to be filled and no space between each other. So i didnt give them a fixed width and height. thats why they are the size of the recyclerview. Is there another way to change the size dynamically according to the screen size to be filled the screen?

Comment: I set the recyclerviews height a fixed size but lets say it is 60dp all the items in it happen to have 60dp height and it still displays one row and you have to scroll down or up to see the other row